# How to list filenames containing a specific string

Tags: linux, command

I've been searching for commands that would print the list of filenames that contain a specific string, regardless if the string is part of a bigger string.

So for instance, say there's a directory with files `"DABC.txt"`, `"ABC.txt"`, `"ABC"`, and `"CDA.txt"`. Then if I want to search for all filenames that contain the word "ABC", the command I'm looking for should print out `"DABC.txt"`, `"ABC.txt"`, and `"ABC"`.

I thought `find -name` would work here, but it only prints out filenames with an exact string that matches the keyword; it does not print out filenames that contain the keyword as a **part** of a string of the filename, not the whole string by itself. (Like `"DABC.txt"`)

Would there be an alternative for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `find . -iname '*abc*'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its pretty simple

list files using ls

```
ls -lrt *ABC*
```

list directory using ls

```
ls -ld *ABC*
```

using ls and grep

```
ls -l | grep -i "ABC"
```

using find command

```
find . -name '*abc*'
```

using case insensitive search in find

```
find . -iname '*abc*'
```

Comment: oh so just adding * to each end of the string makes it work?

Comment: * regex it like we are telling unix anything after ABC should be considered or file should start with ABC, lets say if you want to search for files that contains ABC in between then you can assign * ABC * and in case of ABC as last then *ABC